# bash - string manipulation get string before or after substring

Tags: linux, bash

good day all

this is a noob question, but I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere. Other functions like 'cut' or 'awk' or 'sed' are always mentioned but never using the string expression function (I think it is called)

```
string="hi this is a string.and.it has no purpose other than being here"

searchstring="and"

temp=${string#*$searchstring} # this means everything after "and" will be inserted into temp

echo $temp = "hi this is a string."
```

but say I want everything before "and" and by using the same method which I used to get the temp variable result, thus I want

```
echo $temp = ".it has no purpose other than being here"
```

I have tried

```
temp=${string%*$searchstring} (as I understand, # is from front and % is back)
```

but this returns only string's contents unaltered

*Also, man pages, what is this called, this string expression function, where can I find more indepth information?*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to place the asterisk at the other end of the string.

The asterisk stays for "whatever", so

```
${string%$searchstring*}
```

means "remove from `string` everyting from the `searchstring` onwards".

This is documented in `man bash` under "Parameter Expansion".